# Setting object property with a python module's function

Tags: python, game-engine

Is there a way to set an object property using the return value of a module function like this?

[image]

I'm sure the module works because I can catch the final "value" of the function with that print() in the console.

It works if I put this line instead of the return:

```
bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner["Text"] = value
```

but I would like not use it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, the module functions in BGE work without returning values, and you **can't** set property values that way.

The basic structure of a module function in BGE is:

```py
import bge

# cont is a reference to the controller, similar to bge.logic.getCurrentController()
def functionName(cont):
    own = cont.owner
```

To set property values, you don't need property actuators, just use the syntax:

```py
object["property"] =  value
```

You said you don't want to use that syntax, but along with actuators, it's the only way to set object properties. You don't need to add the property through Blender interface, just set it through the code and it will automatically be added. Also, it works not only for game objects but for scenes as well, and they can store not only the basic types (int, float, str, bool, etc), but any kind of type and reference (including references to other objects). For example:

```py
object1["target"] = object2
```

That way, you can access the `object2` without needing to search for it, just accessing it through the reference.

```py
object1["target"].worldPosition
```